# c++ Player loop problems

Tags: c++, loops, random, void

I wanted to create a simple game, akin to poker, where players are asked if they want to discard dice. It is required that there be at least a pair of dice. For example, if a player has 2 dice with a value of 5, they get 5 points, for 3 dice they get 10 points, and so on.

The script has an issue with counting points and ending a player's turn because it should end if the player cannot reshuffle the array, which they can only do once in the game, and if their dice cannot be paired.

If someone would be interested here's source code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <ctime>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
void fill(vector<int>& player) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        player.push_back(rand() % 6 + 1);
    }
}
int countOccurrences(const vector<int>& array, int value) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
        if (array[i] == value) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
int scoreAndRemove(vector<int>& array, int value, int& playerPoints) {
    int points = 0;
    int occurrences = countOccurrences(array, value);
    if (occurrences >= 2) {
        points = value * occurrences;
        playerPoints += points;
        for (int j = 0; j < array.size();) {
            if (array[j] == value) {
                array.erase(array.begin() + j);
            } else {
                j++;
            }
        }
    } else if (occurrences == 3) {
        points = (value * 2);
        playerPoints += points;
        for (int j = 0; j < array.size();) {
            if (array[j] == value) {
                array.erase(array.begin() + j);
            } else {
                j++;
            }
        }
    } else if (occurrences == 4) {
        points = (value * occurrences);
        playerPoints += points;
        for (int j = 0; j < array.size();) {
            if (array[j] == value) {
                array.erase(array.begin() + j);
            } else {
                j++;
            }
        }
    }
    return playerPoints;
}
void displayResults(const vector<int>& array) {
    bool anythingDisplayed = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
        cout << array[i] << " ";
        anythingDisplayed = true;
    }
    if (!anythingDisplayed) {
        cout << "No dice.";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
bool checkPairing(const vector<int>& array) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
        int occurrences = countOccurrences(array, array[i]);
        if (occurrences >= 2) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
bool endTurn(const vector<int>& player) {
    return player.size() <= 1;
}
bool endGame(const vector<int>& player1, const vector<int>& player2) {
    return endTurn(player1) && endTurn(player2);
}
int countPoints(const vector<int>& player) {
    int points = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 6; ++i) {
        int occurrences = countOccurrences(player, i);
        if (occurrences >= 2) {
            points += i * occurrences;
        } else if (occurrences == 3) {
            points += i * 2;
        } else if (occurrences == 4) {
            points += i * occurrences;
        }
    }
    return points;
}
int main() {
    srand(time(NULL));
    vector<int> dice1;
    vector<int> dice2;
    int playerPoints1 = 0;
    int playerPoints2 = 0;
    fill(dice1);
    fill(dice2);
    bool endTurnPlayer1 = false;
    bool endTurnPlayer2 = false;
    while (!endGame(dice1, dice2)) {
        cout << "Player 1's Turn" << endl;
        cout << "Player 1's Dice: ";
        displayResults(dice1);
        if (checkPairing(dice1)) {
            int action;
            do {
                cout << "What do you want to do? (1 - Discard dice, 2 - Reshuffle, 3 - End turn): ";
                cin >> action;
            } while (action < 1 || action > 3);

            switch (action) {
                case 1: {
                    int value;
                    cout << "Enter the value of the dice to discard (1-6): ";
                    cin >> value;
                    while (value < 1 || value > 6) {
                        cout << "You entered an invalid value. Please enter a value between 1 and 6: ";
                        cin >> value;
                    }
                    playerPoints1 = scoreAndRemove(dice1, value, playerPoints1);
                    break;
                }
                case 2: {
                    dice1.clear();
                    fill(dice1);
                    break;
                }
                case 3: {
                    endTurnPlayer1 = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        } else {
            cout << "No dice to pair. ";
            if (!endTurnPlayer1) {
                cout << "You can reshuffle." << endl;
                dice1.clear();
                fill(dice1);
            } else {
                cout << "End of player 1's turn." << endl;
            }
            endTurnPlayer1 = true;
        }
        cout << "Player 2's Turn" << endl;
        cout << "Player 2's Dice: ";
        displayResults(dice2);
        if (checkPairing(dice2)) {
            int action;
            do {
                cout << "What do you want to do? (1 - Discard dice, 2 - Reshuffle, 3 - End turn): ";
                cin >> action;
            } while (action < 1 || action > 3);
            switch (action) {
                case 1: {
                    int value;
                    cout << "Enter the value of the dice to discard (1-6): ";
                    cin >> value;
                    while (value < 1 || value > 6) {
                        cout << "You entered an invalid value. Please enter a value between 1 and 6: ";
                        cin >> value;
                    }
                    playerPoints2 = scoreAndRemove(dice2, value, playerPoints2);
                    break;
                }
                case 2: {
                    dice2.clear();
                    fill(dice2);
                    break;
                }
                case 3: {
                    endTurnPlayer2 = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        } else {
            cout << "No dice to pair. ";
            if (!endTurnPlayer2) {
                cout << "You can reshuffle." << endl;
                dice2.clear();
                fill(dice2);
            } else {
                cout << "End of player 2's turn." << endl;
            }
            endTurnPlayer2 = true;
        }
        if (endTurnPlayer1 && endTurnPlayer2) {
            break;
        }
    }
    playerPoints1 = countPoints(dice1);
    playerPoints2 = countPoints(dice2);
    cout << "Final Scores:" << endl;
    cout << "Player 1 scores " << playerPoints1 << " points." << endl;
    cout << "Player 2 scores " << playerPoints2 << " points." << endl;
    if (playerPoints1 > playerPoints2) {
        cout << "Player 1 wins!" << endl;
    } else if (playerPoints1 < playerPoints2) {
        cout << "Player 2 wins!" << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "It's a tie!" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Tried: I tried to do it with twice the number of functions for each single player, I tried to rebuild the point counting function using a loop but this is not the optimal solution.

Expecting: So that the program can count points correctly and players' turns end when no dice can be paired and there are no re-draws.

Comment: Unrelated, but your `scoreAndRemove` and `countPoints` functions don't seem to match the specified behavior. Why is the math for 3 matches different? Based on your description, it should simply _always_ be `score += value * (occurrances - 1);` You have way too much copy/paste code everywhere that can lead to mistakes. The scoring logic should exist once. The player input loop should exist once. Instead of distinct variables, use an array to hold player data including their dice and whether they've used their shuffle. Make the main loop switch players with `player = (1 + player) % 2;`

Comment: How do you enter the `else if (occurrences == 3)` statement?  If `occurrences` is 3, this means that it is greater than 2, so it goes into the first `if` statement.  I'm confused.  Have you used a debugger on your code?

Comment: You definitely need to step through your code with a debugger to verify your program behaves the way *you intended*.

Comment: Here's an example of a simpler construction for your game, using my recommendations above: https://godbolt.org/z/MGP6dYa7c -- The game logic is abstracted to allow any hand size, any number of players and any number of sides on the dice. I don't think your game makes a whole lot of sense, because the obvious strategy is to always score every dice possible. I suspect you're missing something extra. Perhaps the hand should be topped up with new dice after removing. I've written the `fill` function to support that. Notice how putting methods into a `Player` class simplifies everything.